# Holomorphic map, Instantons of Complex Projective Space and Loop Group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, complex-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics

It seems that holomorphic (or rational) maps play a crucial role to relate the following data:

1. Instanton in 1-dimensional complex Projective Space $$\mathbb{P}^1$$
   in a 2 dimensional (2d) spacetime.
2. Instanton in a $n$-dimensionalcomplex Projective Space $$\mathbb{P}^n$$
   in a 2 dimensional (2d) spacetime.
3. Instanton in an infinite-dimensional Kahler manifold, the loop group, $$ΩG$$
   which is the loops on the structure group $G$, in a 2 dimensional (2d) spacetime.
4. Instanton in a Yang Mills (YM) theory with the group $G$, in a 4 dimensional (4d) spacetime.

> **Question 1**: What are the constructions of **holomorphic (or rational) maps $F$** from 1. to 2.:
>
> (this shall be more straightforward),
>   $$
> F_{1 \to 2}: \mathbb{P}^j \to \mathbb{P}^n,
> $$
>   from 2. to 3.:
>   $$
> F_{2 \to 3}: \mathbb{P}^n \to ΩG,
> $$
>   from 2. to 4.
>   $$
> F_{2 \to 4}: \mathbb{P}^n \to G \text{ on YM instantons}?
> $$
>   Do we need to fix a particular structure group $G$? (Like special unitary groups?)
>
> **Question 2**: For the above maps, $F_{I \to J}$, is that the instanton number 1 of the theory-$I$ always maps to the instanton number 1 of the theory-$J$? (Namely what is the ratio of the instanton numbers of the maps? Is that always 1:1?)

Ref: Instantons and geometric invariant theory_Comm. Math. Phys_(1984), 453-460_S. K. Donaldson